# How to read/write a boolean array in a Postgres database?

Tags: java, sql, arrays, jdbc, jdbc-postgres

I have a postgres DB containing a table with a boolean array for the days of the week (t/f whether the employee has to work on this day or not).

The table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
        ...,
    weekdays BOOLEAN[7],
        ...
);
```

In my Java servlet I would like to read and write the array using a `boolean[]` (primitive type). I have found out that it should work with the `java.sql.Array` Object.

Inserting does not work with the following:

```
Connection dbcon = DataSource.checkOut();

preparedStatement pstatement = dbcon.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO employee (weekdays) VALUES (?)");
pstatement.setArray(1, dbcon.createArrayOf("BOOLEAN", castToObjectType( objectToInsert.getWorkingdays() ).toArray() ) );
```

...

```
private ArrayList<Boolean> castToObjectType(boolean[] valueArray){
    ArrayList<Boolean> objArray = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    for (int i = 0; i < valueArray.length; i++) {
        objArray.add( new Boolean(valueArray[i]) );
    }

    return objArray;
}
```

I'm getting an `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Unable to find server array type for provided name BOOLEAN` exception.

I'm also somehow stuck the way round doing the conversion from java.sql.Array to `boolean[]`. Ideas, Best practices?

Comment: It's not clear from your question - does your code currently work?

Comment: try to pass `BOOLEAN` in `createArrayOf` in lower case

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov That helped. Thanks a lot. Do you also know how to retrieve the boolean array from database with getArray() ?

Comment: solved also the way back with `getArray` and using `Boolean[]` object type instead of primitive type.

Comment: try (boolean[]) resultSet.getArray("coulmn name").getArray()